# How to store websocket connections for filtering them?

Tags: node.js, websocket, apache-kafka, real-time, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to build a system for a transportation company. The company has many trucks and deliver items to different countries.
One of the use cases of the system is to track each truck and view it's position in real time. So, each truck send GPS data to Kafka topic using "truck_id" as key. Data is send every 1 second.

Let say that data is JSON like this:

```
{
    "truck_id": "STU_28",
    "plate": "ZH1234Z"
    "lat": 47.3688196,
    "lng": 8.5204119
}
```

How can I send these data to client app? This is the part that I get stuck. There are 3 clients, web client, android client and ios client.

This is the use case: one user opens the web client and selects 3 trucks from trucks list. Then clicks a button to display each truck real time position on map(I'm using OpenStreetMap and Leaflet to show the map).

I have search about this and found that I could use websockets for sending data from server to client.
I build a NodeJS server using websocket module but those connections are stored in **MemoryStore**. What I want is to store those connections somewhere else that I can get later.
I found some solutions using **Redis as PUB/SUB** but those solutions where using Socket.IO, I'm using websocket module.
I know that this use case is kind a *publish/subscribe* model.

So trucks publish data(their positions) and users subscribe to those data(to display on map).
The problem is that there are different "groups" of subscribers, for example:

> "user1" wants to show location of trucks ["STU_28", "STU_818", "ZFL_00_1"],
>
> "user2" wants to show location of just one truck,
>
> "user3" wants to show location of 5 other trucks etc.

When user navigates to another page or logs out from web app the websocket connection needs to terminate. So I have to remove the connection from store.
Also this service(nodejs or another) acts as a Kafka consumer, gets data from Kafka topic and send it to users app.

A pseudo code could be like this:

```
KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer();
        
consumer.subscribe(topicName);
        
while(true) {
    // position is json data like above which contains "truck_id"
    position = consumer.poll();

    // go to websocket connection store and get all users(connections) that had searched(subscribed) to that "truck_id"
    connections = wsConnectionStore.getConnections(position.truck_id);
    
    for(WSConnection connection : connections) {
        connection.sendUTF(position);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? No necessary to be in nodejs, it can be in java, python.

Note: the system needs to be scalable and highly available.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. To me this question is far too broad to be answered here on SO. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ideally narrow your question to a specific programming question, ideally with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bourne Did you find any approach for this?

Comment: @Hmmm Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: @bourne ... so I have manged to do it by adding some of the user info which is required to filter out the data we need to send him, and for each of the notification I need to send I loop through connection just like you are doing above and send the filtered data on that particular channel

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems not very concise, but It is a good problem to discuss. In fact, I am also building an app with similar use cases.

*Storing the websockets*

My research has led me towards a solution of keeping sockets stored in memory and not externally. Websockets use relatively few resources. This causes some extra effort when dealing with scaling (update: websockets in a distributed system may require sticky sessions depending on the use case).

*Many groups to many trucks*

One solution is to use references to your connections. An example would be pointers. Each truck has a list of subscribers and when the truck has new data it pushes to all in the list. The lists are only references to your connections.

```
Truck1 => [user1,user2,user3]
truck2 => [user2,user3,user5]
```

*My personal thoughts on a solution (depending on your requirements)*

I don't see the necessity of updating the data every 1 second for a truck. The difference in location of a truck with an average speed of 60mph from second1 to second2 or second5 seems almost negligible. However, if this is required, then is it also required that the client receive the update every 1 sec?

I might suggest not using websockets. Instead, cache the truck data server side and keep it updated on the required interval. On the client side sent a request to the server based on a reasonable refresh rate that gets the desired truck positions. Server can quickly retrieve the cached data and return.

Comment: Welcome :) I am not sure what you mean by `This causes some extra effort when dealing with scaling but it seems using a kind of server ID in the header makes it more possible.`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I didn't know what it was called at the time but I was referring to server-affinity or setting up sticky sessions. Using websockets in a distributed system would require some extra attention in the case your connections are in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are open to do some changes, I believe that using node.js with socket.io you can achieve the desired behaviour using socket.io rooms.
Each truck should be a room and users that want to follow those trucks should subscribe to their room. With this when a truck position is updated all subscribers would be notified.
If you applications has more than one instance you should consider using a [redis adaptor](https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/) so all instances have access to all clients.